# Stored Procedure to construct sql query - SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables "Tbl1" which contains 3 rows as shown in table below

```
  ColNames
  *********
   Name
   SurName
   DOB
```

My second table "tbl2" Contains the info related to Name, SurName and DOB as shown below:

```
Name        SurName      DOB
***********************************
SAM         billing      22/11/2000
NULL        petres       22/11/2000
BILL        Jones        NULL
Dave        NULL         22/11/2000
```

Hypothetically, if **Name and DOB** are chosen from tbl1, I would like to extract the NOT NULL values from the second table.

JOINS is NOT an option here, so please dont suggest that. sorry....

What I have done thus far is built a stored procedure that has saved **Name and DOB** as rows from tbl1 into a #temp_table.

I want to now build some sort of stored procedure that would build a query for me that will select "NOT NULL" values from tbl2.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spShowRuleValues
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' + 'tbl2' + ' WHERE '+
    stuff((SELECT ', ' + Header FROM #temp_table
    FOR Xml path('')
    ),1,2,'') + ' IS NOT NULL ';
END

execute spShowRuleValues
```

But, upon executing this stored procedure, I am only able to develop a query which is:

```
`SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE Name, DOB IS NOT NULL `
```

How can I build the query in a way that it builds up as:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE Name IS NOT NULL AND
DOB IS NOT NULL
```

and then to execute this query to get the results from tbl1 excluding the NOT NULL values.

Please feel free to suggest another approach that i can use to construct desired query. Thank you for your time and consideration in advance.

Comment: Why are joins not an option? that would be the simplest, most efficient way of achieving this

Comment: @SEarle1986  thanks for asking, Because the way table structure is, there are no foreign keys linking them, I know you would say that is a table design flaw, but that's the problem I am trying to work with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH` a little bit.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spShowRuleValues
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @WhereCondition VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF(
        (
            SELECT 'AND T.' + QUOTENAME(Header) + ' IS NOT NULL' FROM #temp_table FOR Xml path('')
        ),1,4,'');

    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM tbl2 AS T WHERE '+ @WhereCondition

END
```